# Ubuntu 16.04 LUKS passcode does not appear

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, luks

I installed an encrypted version of Ubuntu on my PC. If I start my computer appears this login screen: [image]

I'm unable to type in the passcode. Nothing appears. Also if I type in the correct passcode and hit enter nothing changes.
I solved this Problem by pressing the restart button. Now this screen appears and I'm able to enter my passcode: [image]

Is there a possibility to get the second screen at normal boot?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with LUKS. Im using Nvidias 367.27 graphics driver. My /etc/default/grub file looks like that:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

If you are missing anything just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar problem for older versions of ubuntu. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1375435

The solution being used there also worked for me at Ubuntu 16.04.

Add this to /etc/default/grub : `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=wxh`
and update the configuration with `update-grub` .