# How to enable text-mode LUKS passphrase prompt on boot?

Tags: boot, 16.04, luks, passphrase

I'm on Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 and I changed graphic card to GeForce 8600GT and now I can't enter LUKS password on boot after installing NVIDIA propriatary drivers (I tried 304.135 and 340.102). Keyboard does not work there, I only have such screen and I can't enter anything:

[image]

To boot my OS I need to go through recovery mode and it boots fine, but I would like to fix it by perhaps changing that passphrase screen to text-mode. I know that there should be such mode for this as I have it on another machine with another GeForce, only thing that it's on 14.04 and it switched to text-mode automatically right after installing NVIDIA driver.

How do I do this on 16.04?

PS. I've tried [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/a/802278) solution (both `wxh` and `text`) and it does not work for me - not any passphrase screen appears...

Comment: Did you try installing `nvidia-375` from apt?

Comment: Same issue, but can't even boot to recovery mode on 375 - getting FAILED on some Braille Device Support...

Comment: What happens if you remove the boot options `quiet splash`? You can do so quickly if you select a Grub entry, enter editing mode with the keyboard shortcut "C", edit the line starting with `linux` accordingly and press Ctrl+X to execute the listed commands.

Comment: Oh! So simple! Needed to remove it from `/etc/default/grub` as Ctrl+X does not work here... and it looks like recovery mode, only don't need to go through GRUB and recovery mode, so it's good enough for me :) If you want, you can make an answer out of this, I'll give you those points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have enabled this on my Ubuntu 16.04 server that has XFCE installed.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` with your text editor of choice, and remove the option `quiet splash`, and then if this does not work I would suggest also adding `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text` on a new line in `/etc/default/grub`. Remember, after you make a change to the grub config file, you should always run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to apply the changes.